# Output message from java process to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, process, jtextarea

I have tried the others link on this portion, but still unable to get what I need. Thus I would like to seek help from the group here.

Below is my code:

```
try {
                String file = new File("iperf3.exe").getCanonicalPath();
                String cmd1[] = {file,"-c","ping.online.net","-P","10","-w","710000"};
                Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);

                BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));

                String line1;
                while ((line1 = input1.readLine()) != null) {
                    txtConsole1.setText(line1);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The output message to the textArea is only the last message from executing the command. May I know how can I stream all the output messages into the textArea?

Thank you.

Comment: You're either block the EDT or violating the single rules of Swing, in either case not pretty.  Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding previous content of `txtConsole1` by calling `txtConsole1.setText(line1);`. Get all your output in variable and at last set content in `txtConsole1`

```
String line1;
String content;
while ((line1 = input1.readLine()) != null) {
    content += line1;
}
txtConsole1.setText(content);
```